# how to remove a project from coverity-scan

Tags: coverity

I've registered a project with [coverity-scan](https://scan.coverity.com) in the past.

I would now like to remove that project from coverity-scan (or at least from my dashboard; but preferrably i'd like to remove the project entirely).

I'm stuck as there seems to be no such option in the web-interface. am i missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't.  I've just asked Coverity's support to delete one and got the reply:

> We generally do not delete projects from SCAN as we keep aggregate metrics on the projects.

Comment: Unless, I think, registered project has not submitted any builds yet as I mention in my question here https://stackoverflow.com/q/48175947/151641

Answer (score 0):

There's a "Delete Your Project" button in the very bottom of "Project Settings" page.

Comment: no, unfortunately there is none. the project in question has been created a while ago, and while i see the "Delete Your Project" button in my newer projects, it definitely lacks in this one.

Comment: I created a new project a few days ago, and there is no "Delete Your Project" button today. I thought I recalled seeing it on the day I created it, but couldn't be sure, so thought I was going slightly mad when I couldn't find it today. I have a second project created in March with no delete button either.

Answer (score 0):

The Delete Your Project button is only available to the administrator of a project and only if a build has not yet been submitted for analysis.