# Coverity Scan does not release name of deleted project

Tags: github, coverity

I maintain coverity for nanodbc project at https://scan.coverity.com/projects/lexicalunit-nanodbc

I also registered new project for nanodbc at https://scan.coverity.com/projects/nanodbc-nanodbc that points to new location of git repository at GitHub.

I realised I can rename the old existing project pointing to that new location.

1. I went to Coverity Scan > nanodbc/nanodbc > Project Settings and deleted the project. Yes, there was Delete button - apparently, it is available for projects which have not submitted any builds yet.
2. I went to Coverity Scan > lexicalunit/nanodbc > Project Settings > hit Rename button > selected nanodb/nanodbc repository at GitHub from the drop-down list
3. Scan Coverity failed to rename with "Name already registered".

[image]

Loading https://scan.coverity.com/projects/nanodbc-nanodbc gives HTTP 404, so the project has been deleted indeed, but the name apparently has not been released.

Why Coverity does not allow to re-use name of deleted project? Isn't there any workaround?

Is that due to [this explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36703264/151641):

> We generally do not delete projects from SCAN as we keep aggregate metrics on the projects.

As I mentioned, the nanodbc/nanodbc project I created initially had not submitted any builds to analyze.

By the way, Coverity Scan via Twitter [does not seem to be responsive](https://twitter.com/mloskot/status/950483798495555590)

Comment: Have you tried emailing the scan admin?

Comment: @Caleb thanks for the suggestion. I've just e-mailed the admin.

Comment: Coverity is not responsive over anywhere, not just Twitter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Coverity Scan support team confirmed the issue responding to my e-mail with this:

> Unfortunately a long standing bug regarding renames in SCAN which does
>   not update the associate project resources. We can remove the existing
>   projects for you so that you can start from scratch.